# How to remove a right noise from this image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pixel

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
```

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here. Please provide a [mre] to your _specific_ problem. What have you tried so far? Please show any relevant code. So, what is the expected output? Just the large black blob in the middle? Inverse binary threshold the image, and again find contours, and reject anything below a certain threshold. The center blob is way larger than the stuff on the right side. I'm quite certain, that should work!

Comment: Tell us in words what distinguishes the object of interest from the "noise". (I know what you mean but it matters to objectivate the obvious.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you wish to have only the middle part of the image and remove everything else from the image. One simple way is to search for contours, select the bounding box of the biggest contour and draw it out on a newly created mask.

Example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU+cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cv2.RETR_TREE)[0]
cnt = max(contours, key=lambda c: cv2.contourArea(c))
mask = np.ones((img.shape[:2]), np.uint8)*255
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite("mask.png", mask)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

EDIT:

This is how I would try to make it based on your input image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(
    blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cv2.RETR_TREE)[0]
cnt = max(contours, key=lambda c: cv2.contourArea(c))
mask = np.ones((img.shape[:2]), np.uint8)*255
mask2 = np.zeros((img.shape[:2]), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, (0, 0, 0), -1)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
mask2[y:y+h, x:x+w] = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('mask2', mask2)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how can i integrate this code with my already existing, sorry if it is beginer question, I just started working with this library. I edited question(code is there)

Comment: Can you post the original image (before any processing)? Because I can't really see what the problem is in implementing this answer to the posted code.

Comment: Thank you, it would be cool if you will be able to combine them, i am having hard time to do it. I added

Comment: @Jack Have a look at the edit. Is this what u wanted?